# How to design a model for contour recognition? In particular, how to shape the output layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, contour

I want to design and train a **neural network** for the **automatic recognition of the edges**, in some microscopic images.
I am using Keras for a start, I may consider PyTorch later.

The **structure** of the images is rather simple, with some **dark areas**, and some **clear areas**, relatively easy to distinguish, and the task is to select the pixels of the contour between *dark* and *clear* areas. The transition between dark and clear is gradual, so my result is not a single line of edge pixels, but rather a 10 or 15 pixels wide "ribbon" at the edge.

I have manually annotated 200-something images, so for each image I have another image, of the same size, where the pixels of the contours are black, and all the other pixels are white.

I have seen many tutorials on how to *design*, *compile* and *fit* a model (a neural network), and then how to test it, using the manually annotated data.

However, most of the tutorials work on problems of classification, where the number of neurons in the output layer is the number of categories.

My problem is **not a problem of classification**, and ideally my output should be an image of the same size of the input.

So, here is my question:

*What is the best way to design the output layer? Is a layer with a number of neurons equal to the number of pixels the best idea? Or this is a waste, and there is a more efficient way?*

---

**Addendum**

1. The images are "easy", but it is still difficult to find the contour pixels, so I believe that it is worth using the machine learning approach.
2. The transition between dark and clear is a little gradual, so my result is not a single line of pixels on the edge, but rather a band, a 10 or 15 wide ribbon of edge pixels. Since I am after a ribbon of pixels, my categories should be "edge" and "not-edge". If I use the categories "dark pixels" and "clear pixels", and then numerically find the pixels between the two areas I do not get the "ribbon" result, which I need.

Comment: Look into image segmentation, stuff like U-net will work well I think. Also, might just be me but your overuse of bolding and italics actually made it harder for me to read your question.

Comment: You also might not need a neural net at all if what you're working with is "rather simple... easy to distinguish"

Comment: Why do you want a neural net for such simple task? Use Canny or LoG filter for a start.

Comment: I have removed some of the bolding, I hope the text is more readable now.

The areas are "comparatively easy" to identify, but it is still challenging. I have tried with algorithms based on the pixel gradients, and other numerical analysis, but I am not happy with the results.
I believe that it is at least worth to try with machine learning.
I have found literature that report the use of machine learning for similar problems. But in the scientific literature they do not give such technical and "mundane" details... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "**yes**": *it is a good idea to have as many neurons in output as you have in input, i.e. to output an image with the same resolution of the input images*.

The network architecture will have an input layer with a neuron for each pixel, then typically the hidden layers will shrink to less neurons, probably with *convolutional* layers, and then some more layers will re-expand the number of neurons, up to the output layer, which in principle may have the same number of neurons as the input layer.

The most common architecture in this type of problem is the **U-net architecture**, described in the article "*U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical Image Segmentation*", by Ronneberger, Fischer, and Brox, published on the open arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597.

[[image: U-net architecture, as described in the article "U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical Image Segmentation", by Ronneberger, Fischer, and Brox, published on the open arxiv: ][1]]